# PL/SQL How to sum values from on table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE tb_low_qty 
( tb_id serial NOT NULL, 
tb_pt_code integer, 
tb_pt_name character varying(128), 
tb_pt_qty numeric, 
tb_move_name character varying(250), 
CONSTRAINT tb_low_qty_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tb_id) )
```

i want to sum tb_pt_qty where tb_pt_code = tb_pt_code
how to create pl/sql?

Comment: What is  tb_pt_code = tb_pt_code ? do you want total sum of tb_pt_qty without any where condition ?

Comment: Hm... `tb_pt_code = tb_pt_code` should be true for all rows where tb_pt_code isn't NULL.

Comment: @Pragnesh Khalas iwant to sum tb_pt_qty when value in tb_pt_code equals

Answer (score 0):

So Check Below query

```
SELECT SUM(tb_pt_qty) AS tb_pt_qty FROM tb_low_qty WHERE  tb_pt_code =  Your Value
```